# Logical NOT in xaml

Tags: xaml, logic

is there a way to check for logical not in XAML. Im attempting to bind to widely used property, but for these new bindings its the wrong way round. I dont want to modify the property, so is there a way to to invert the boolean result in xaml?

Answer (score 3):

Yes it's a way you could use Converter to do it and use the Converter in your Binding.

[Binding Converter Example MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.converter.aspx)